# JQuery getting a data attribute returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of data-scanID from the clicked tag and store it inside a variable called scanID but the alert comes up undefined.

```
$("#trucklist").click(function(event) {
    var scanID=$(event.target).data("scanID");
    alert(scanID);
});
```

The html looks something like this:

```
<ul id="trucklist">
    <li data-scanID=*somedata*>
        <ul>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-scanID=*somedata*>
        <ul>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-scanID=*somedata*>
        <ul>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
            <li>*stuff*</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are targetting `ul`. Try this:

```
$("#trucklist > li").click(function(event) {
    var scanID=$(this).data("scanID");
    alert(scanID);
});
```

The above will target the `trucklist`'s child `li` and alert you its `data`.

Also, I would suggest you to wrap the attribute's value within quotes.

Also, data attributes cannot contain capital letters. So change them or it will not work.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXYZ4/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that isn't working. I changed the data-scanID to just data-scan and used your code, now the click event isn't even firing. Also I can't put quotes around the data because all this html is being written from a for loop in an ajax call and the *somedata* is data brought in from the ajax. The data-scanID's do have the proper data in them though because I checked it with inspect element.

Comment: @chrispytoes in that case try `$('#trucklist > li').on('click', function() { ... });`.

Comment: @mdesdev Yeah still not working, the click event doesn't even get triggered.

Comment: @chrispytoes oook...try `$(document).on('click','#trucklist > li', function() { ... });`

Comment: Hi @chrispytoes if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the green check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.